# which one is better - s3+cloudfront+waf OR ec2+security group when allowing a specific IP in a frontend built with React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm planning to deploy a web frontend with React. I have two conditions: I need to allow only specific IP addresses, and I want a cost-effective solution. I have come up with two options, and I would like to know which one is better.

The first option is to use S3 and CloudFront for deployment and then block specific IP addresses using WAF (Web Application Firewall). Initially, with S3 alone, I could allow only specific IP addresses using S3 policies. However, since I need to apply HTTPS, I understand that using CloudFront allows me to configure IP whitelisting with WAF.

Additionally, I have considered another approach that does not involve S3 policies or WAF but instead involves determining the IP whitelist in the middleware of the React app. I would like to know your thoughts on this approach.

The second option is to deploy the frontend on EC2. I thought about using Docker Compose on EC2 to deploy Nginx and the React web application. In this case, I intended to manage the IP whitelist in the security group.

Which method do you think is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host a React app with an IP whitelist I would choose S3 and CloudFront, because of the benefits of being a managed service: no maintenance or updates except the React app itself. This can also scale up without any additional effort.

### S3 and CloudFront

- This is a managed service: you don't get your hands on the server or get to choose what software it runs, but it is less maintenance and you aren't responsible for software updates except your React app.
- Pricing is per use. The higher use the higher cost. This can be very cheap for low usage/traffic apps. The cost is more difficult to predict.
- Scaling up is easy due to the 'serverless' architecture.
- CDN and caching is built in or out of the box.
- SSL/HTTPS is out of the box.

### EC2

- This an unmanaged service which requires more time and effort. You are responsible for the setup, maintenance and updates. There's a higher chance of security issues and vulnerabilities.
- You get more control but I cannot see any benefit for a React app.
- Pricing is predictable with a consistent cost per month.
- Scaling needs
  to be managed by you: with enough traffic/load, you will need more EC2 instances with a load balancer.
- CDN and caching needs to be configured. You can create a CloudFront distribution, but at this point you might as well have gone with the CloudFront option in the first place.
- SSL/HTTPS needs to be configured by you (for example with LetsEncrypt).

Comment: Thank you,sir. and then I would like to hear your thoughts on determining the IP whitelist. Which do you think is more appropriate between setting the IP in the middleware of React and configuring the IP whitelist in WAF?

Comment: I would use the WAF, which you can use for either the S3/CloudFront or the EC2 option.

Comment: As you said, I deployed waf + s3 + cloudfront Thank you !! Have a nice day:D

Comment: @giwony Hey, we have the same setup but ran into issues on waf setting up rules. 
Initially setup cloudfront with a 403 -> index.html redirect so non root URL requests would properly render. But now if someone is firewalled off, all the files in the cloudfront are loaded in the network tab, but they all point to the index.html .  Did you have any conditional error message processing to get around this?

Comment: @ChrisConaty  Wouldn't it be possible to solve it by setting the error page or behavior separately on the cloudfront? I've never experienced a similar error. If you've solved it, please let me know!